# How do i count the size of an str-type array?

Tags: c

I am currently creating a function that needs to append new str elements to an already existing array that I don't really know the size of since every str does not have the same size.

I tried using the sizeof() function but since I don't know the size of every str I don't see it working. I also tried to use a technique I found:

```
char* liste[]={"one","two","three","four","five"};
int size = *(&liste + 1) - liste; 
printf(size);
```

Instead of a size I get a "Program Received signal SIGSEGV"

Comment: Arrays are not dynamic data types in C; that is, you can't just append values to them unless you plan it out in advance. Can you explain what you're trying to a bit more clearly?

Comment: if the array is fixed size, then you can calculate the size using sizeof. each string is a pointer so you only need to know the number of strings in the array. HOWEVER like Carl said, you cannot append to the array so it's useless. If you are reallocating the array, then it is dynamic and sizeof no longer works. In that case, you need to save the current size in a variable and update it whenever you reallocate. This would apply if you are allocating with malloc or calloc initially and then using realloc when it needs to grow.

Comment: `printf(size);` is wrong..you know that, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that double-quoted string literals in C—and all arrays for that matter—generally act like *pointers* (for string literals, specifically, they act like `char*`s). In this case you've created an array of pointers to arrays of `char`s; the outermost array's size is the size of a pointer, times the number of elements. (All the strings themselves are stored somewhere else.)

If you want to get the number of elements, *and that's known at compile-time*, you can use `sizeof(liste)/sizeof(liste[0])`. If it's not known at compile-time, you'll have to add some other way of tracking it, such as a NULL at the end or a separate variable holding the size. (Double-quoted strings use this first option: `"hello"` is roughly equivalent to `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0]`.)

As far as the `SIGSEGV`, though: `printf` takes a string—that is, a pointer—as its first argument. When you give it a number, it tries to use it as a pointer, runs head-first into some memory it's not supposed to access, and the operating system kills it with `SIGSEGV`. The proper way to print a number is something like `printf("%d", my_int)`.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to address the fact that every "string"' in C is *nul-terminated*. Thus to find the length of each string, you start at the beginning and scan forward until you reach the `'\0'` (or you include `string.h` and let `strlen` do it for you)

Comment: String literals are actually stored in static memory as arrays of `char`, not `const char`. These arrays _decay_ to pointers to `char` in most expressions, but string literals are not pointers, and not to `const char`. It is UB to attempt to modify the contents of the arrays associated with string literals, so it is a best practice to use `const char` when assigning pointers to the elements of these arrays.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note added!

Comment: @DavidBowling Edited

Comment: @DavidBowling good point, and specifying `-std=c11` and `-pedantic` will warn of the deprecated use of `char *` instead of `const char *`. (on all sane systems -- for those with modifiable literals, I haven't tried)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- I see no warnings with `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` using gcc 6.3.0, and I don't remember anything about deprecated use of `char *` for string literals in the C11 Standard. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Draconis -- note that `sizeof "some string of characters"` will yield the size of the array in static storage instead of the size of a pointer.

Comment: Yes, now you got me going, gaah! it C++ that issues the deprecated warning - sorry.

Comment: Aarrgh. C++ again! ;)

Comment: It's the old `"warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]"` -- I got to stay away from the dark side...

Comment: String literals are char arrays, not pointers. The array is an array of char pointers because it was declared as `char* liste[]`  , the contents of the initializers cannot affect the type of an object

Comment: Detail: What you are calling "double-quoted strings" in C are _string literals_ ( a C language term).  One of the differences between them and _strings_ (a C library term) is that a _string literal_ can have multiple _null characters_ in it whereas a _string_ only has the one.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: sizeof(liste) will no longer return the full size of the array in Windows, but only the size of the pointer. The standard libraries in Windows have quietly changed this to allow for use of their additional libraries such as std:array and std::iterator. You will need to use the functions from these libraries or create your own methods to count the elements. This is a sample for those that cannot use std::array or std::iterator due to library conflicts or other reasons.

```
size_t SizeOfArray(std::string* inComing)
{
  size_t outGoing = 0;
  bool end = false;
  // Validate Array
  if (inComing != NULL)
  {
    // Appended arrays can be valid or not. Sometimes earlier cleanup
    // will link to an empty array location, so check for empty and invalid. 
    while ((!end) && (inComing[outGoing].size() != 0))
    {
      __try
      {
        // if an appended memory location has value, but is not an array
        // you look for the NULL character. For wstrings change '\0' to L'\0'.
        // If the memory location is not valid, it will throw the exception.
        if (inComing[outGoing].c_str()[inComing[outGoing].length()] != '\0')
        {
          // End of array -  if nice empty value
          end = true;
        }
        else
        {
          outGoing++; // Count each valid string in the array
        }
      }
      // This is the blank exception catch to an extra element that is not
      // valid.
      __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
      {
      // End of array -  if unknown value
      end = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return outGoing; // Return the count
}
```